# PowerAutomate get SOURCE of email body

Tags: power-automate

I need to access the source of an email body through PowerAutomate. Unfortunately the standard *HTML to Text - Body* solution doesn't work as the emails I want to watch have an embedded link to our ERP  (Coupa) and I only get this:

```
[https://urldefense.com/v3/__http:/www.coupa.com__;!!longstring]
```

When checking the source of the email body (or actually opening the email), the string I'm looking for is there but Google failed me on how to actually get the source of an email instead of the above conversion.

Full scope: watch inbox for automated emails generated for supplier registration requests, add row to spreadsheet with supplier's name, material group (regex match) and responsible person (xlookup in the table)

Answer (score 0):

Using *Compose - Body* instead of *HTLM to Text* gets the source of the email body.